# What is a good way to create a table of mapping functions to apply to each query parameter in Java

Tags: java, enums, static, transform

My Java REST service accepts some query parameters and values. I want to apply some transformation functions to these parameter and values before I pass these to another service through REST API. I want to know the best way to transform these parameters in such a way that it can be as clean as possible for extension.

Here was my attempt to do this before and hope it also illustrates this better -
I created an enum which takes a Function like this:

```
public enum MyQueryParam {
    ID("id", new MyCryptoFunction()),
    PRICE("price", new CurrencyConvertFunction()),
    ...

    private String mappedParam;
    private Function<String, String> mappingFunction;

    MyQueryParam(String mappedParam, Function<String, String> mappingFunction) {
        this.mappedParam = mappedParam;
        this.mappingFunction = mappingFunction;
    }

    public String getMappedParam() {
        return mappedParam;
    }
}

static class MyCryptoFunction implements Function<String, String> {
    public String apply(String msg) {
        // do the hash function
    }
}

// .. somewhere in the code where I get the query params and values as a map
paramMap.forEach((param, value) -> uriBuilder.addParameter(param.getMappedParam(), param.mappingFunction.apply(value)));
```

So my id parameter gets encrypted and my price parameter gets currency converted statically.

Problem now comes when, these transformations need to be done based on some additional context that comes with each parameter. For example, I want to pass the locale from the request to the CurrencyConvertFunction. And I want to pass a secret key to the CryptoFunction. I cannot do new CurrencyConvertFunction(locale) in the enum given its static. What is a clean and elegant way to map my query parameters to applying some transformations and make it extensible?

(For example, I can check the value of the param as I am iterating through each parameter and do the validation there, but that feels like making the code un-maintainable).

Comment: Hi, could you explain in general terms *what* are you trying to accomplish rather than the *how*. I don't really get to understand completely. Thank you!

Comment: I rearranged/rephrased it a bit so that the first para more explicitly explains the end goal.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can update `MyCryptoFunction` to

```
static class MyCryptoFunction implements Function<Pair<String, String>, String> {
    public String apply(Pair<String, String> param) {
        // do the hash function
    }
}
```

and also change the type of `mappingFunction` in `MyQueryParam` accordingly.

Then you can call the `mappingFunction` as

```
param.mappingFunction.apply(Pair.of(value,"additionalParam")).
```

You can also replace `Pair` with your custom class if you like.

Comment: In the caller when I am looping through each param, I have to check the param before assigning the additional parameter. Example:
```
if ID.equals(param) 
  param.mappingFunction.apply(Pair.of(value,"additionalParamForId"));
if PRICE.equals(param)
 param.mappingFunction.apply(Pair.of(value,"additionalParamForPrice"));
```
I wish to avoid that check.

Comment: you can iterate over params as you mentioned in the question and then have a switch/case for param type

Comment: the only way you can avoid those conditions or switch/case is by building a map for the additional params like `Map< MyQueryParam, String> additionalParams` and then  `param.mappingFunction.apply(Pair.of(value, additionalParams.get(param)))`

Comment: Ok. I will go with that approach.